# Why isn't access to /proc/pid/mem a security vulnerability?

Tags: linux, memory, proc

I've played around a bit with `/proc/pid/mem` and `/proc/pid/maps`. I wrote a simple c program that just periodically reads from a variable (whose address is written to stdout), and I was able to change its value with `dd`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    int value = 5;

    do {
        printf("value: %d\naddress: %p\npid: %d\n", value, &value, pid);
    } while (getchar() != -1);

    return 0;
}
```

```bash
echo '0x2a000000' | xxd -p -r | dd of=/proc/$PID/mem bs=1 seek=$((ADDR)) count=4 conv=notrunc
```

When I hit enter in the first program, the value gets updated to 42.

So my question is, why isn't this a problem? I didn't even have root access. If I had installed malware onto my computer it could read/write to any programs' memory.

Even if you don't know the exact address of the variable you can still print out the entire stack and heap using the addresses of `/proc/pid/maps`.

Comment: You only have access to `/proc/<pid>/mem` for processes that are running as your UID. I'm not sure that's any more of a security vulnerability than the fact that any program you run can create/delete/rename/modify any files that you own.